# Gnome-Terminal, how to start in a different directory?

Tags: linux, console, terminal, gnome

Whenever I start my console `gnome-terminal` in Ubuntu, it starts in the home directory. How can I make it start in a different directory say `~/myfolder`?
I tried to write `cd ~/myfolder` in `~/.profile` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you start gnome-terminal like `gnome-terminal --working-directory=myfolder` it will start with the working directory at `~/myfolder` so you could add a new entry to your menu to use that command instead of the other one.

Comment: Also see another (better) solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844677/gemone-terminal-how-to-start-in-a-different-directory/844711#844711

Comment: Note that in Krusader terminal settings this should be without "=" so this should work: `gnome-terminal --working-directory %d`.

Comment: This no longer works in Ubuntu 16.04, due to a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1587154 Please go there and click 'this affects me too' if you'd like it fixed.

Answer (score 13):

I did this way - with script:
open 3 tabs in the same window size 170x40, each "tab" starts in a different directory.

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=170x40 --working-directory=myfolder1 \

--tab --working-directory=myfolder2 \

--tab --working-directory=myfolder3
```

Comment: Most general solution imo. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This no longer works in Ubuntu 16.04, due to a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1587154 Please go there and click 'this affects me too' if you'd like it fixed.

Answer (score 12):

Add the following to your ~/.bashrc

```
cd ~/myfolder
```

Comment: It worked too along with this (link below), but this one is a better solution I guess.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844677/gemone-terminal-how-to-start-in-a-different-directory/844704#844704

Comment: from "this is a better solution", I mean adding to ~/.bashrc

Comment: There is a caveat with ~/.bashrc i.e., if you open a new tab in terminal, you go back to ~/myfolder, which is usually undesirable.
so now I think gnome-terminal --working-directory=myfolder is rather a better solution.

Comment: This is not how bashrc is meant to be used. If you do this, it will affect every interactive shell you run, not just the ones that run in gnome-terminal. If you want to control gnome-terminal, then set something that affects just gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 5):

### Directory option

There is the option  `--working-directory` to specify the startup directory of the terminal (no short option form).

The basic approach to open the terminal in `/some/dir` is

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/some/dir
```

but there is a trap...

### Bad trap

Assuming we want to start the terminal in the directory `~/dir`.

**This does not work:**

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=~/dir
```

The command looks perfectly fine according to the option syntax, but the terminal starts in the home directory.
It's because it does not expand the tilde (`~`), for confusing reasons - see below.

Thesse do work:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/auser/dir

gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME/dir

gnome-terminal --working-directory ~/dir
```

### Tilde expansion

Note there is no `=` in the last variant. Because of this, the `~` is at the start of a shell word, and therefore is handeled by tilde expansion.

The problem is that `~` does not get expanded everywhere, but only in certain places. One of them is in variable assignments, like `directory=~/dir`. That's ok, `~` gets expanded to `$HOME`, but `--working-directory=~/dir` does not expand `~`, because that is not a variable assignment, it only looks very similar.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with relative paths? Example `gnome-terminal --working-directory ..` doesn't work, it actually opens at `/`, no matter where you are currently.

Comment: @sanjarcode `gnome-terminal --working-directory "$(realpath ..)"`

Comment: @sanjarcode to be precise, technically it actually behaves correctly, only that ".." is taken as an absolute path. There is a directory named `/..`, which is the same as `/.` and `/`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [nautilus-open-terminal](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/05/13/nautilus-open-terminal-terminal-quick-launch/) extension. This allows you to right-click on a folder in nautilus and open a terminal window with that directory as its working directory.

You can also run a terminal in the normal way, type "cd ", and drag a folder icon from nautilus to the window. This will paste the path of the folder into the command line and you then type return to change to that directory. You can do the same thing with regular files to paste their path and run commands on them.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is how I turn it off for everyone by default.

```
gconftool-2 --direct \
--config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory/ \
--set -- type=bool /apps/nautilus-open-terminal/desktop_opens_home_dir true
```

Comment: Turn what off ... ?

Answer (score 1):

From [GNOME Terminal - Getting Started](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-get-started.html.en):

> You can also specify a command that runs automatically when you start GNOME Terminal in the profile.

Comment: Well that's what i did. Wrote `cd ~/myfolder` in `./.profile`. It didn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder has a complicated path, ie not just `~/myfolder`, you could create a symlink to it in your home directory so you can get to it quickly. You can also set the `CDPATH` environment variable to tell bash to search a list of directories when you type `cd myfolder`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm impressed by 
[Neil's Mayhew comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844677/gnome-terminal-how-to-start-in-a-different-directory/844711#comment3386972_844711) 
and 
[Volker's Siegel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073924/4672928). I've tried to not only set default directory for
**gnome-terminal** but preserve habitual behavior of desktop environment as well (I'm using *Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon*, 
*GNOME Terminal 3.6.2*, perhaps it also can be applied for other Gnome-congenered DEs). So let me put my two cents in.

1. Adding `cd ~/myfolder` at the very end of `~/.bashrc` does the job. But as already mentioned it will affect every 
   interactive shell. Even more, if you open some directory in a file manager (*Nemo* or *Nautilus* or something like 
   this) and appeal to the context menu from there (e.g. right click and then select **Open in Terminal**) new instance of 
   **gnome-terminal** will be started in `~/myfolder` regardless of the folder which was loaded in the file manager.
   Even if you run `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/some/other/folder` explicitly it will still open `~/myfolder`. Seems that the
   approach with `.bashrc` is unusable.
2. `gnome-terminal --working-directory=myfolder` works fine but only when you use custom menu entry in you DE 
   (or custom shortcut on desktop) which runs terminal with this parameter. If you would like to run **gnome-terminal** from command line
   or from mini-launcher (press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>),  you have to type the parameter every time. Anyway this approach is more-or-less usable.

---

How **gnome-terminal** determines which folder to open? When `--working-directory` is not specified it opens current 
working directory (e.g. `$PWD`) otherwise it opens directory specified explicitly.

I've found the following solution.

Create a file named `gnome-terminal` in your `~/bin` folder. It will act as shortcut but from everywhere (start menu, 
mini-launcher, other terminal instance, etc) because `~/bin` is already in `$PATH` (at least in Linux Mint...). Make this file
executable. Then put the following content into the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

home_directory=~

if [ "$PWD" == "$home_directory" ]; then
    # When 'gnome-terminal' was ran from either 
    #     - start menu
    #     - mini-launcher
    #     ... 
    # parent directory is set to $HOME.
    #
    # We respect original command line arguments. 
    # For example, when terminal is ran from another 
    # terminal instance and '--working-directory' is 
    # specified explicitly we should left it as it is.  
    # If there are two '--working-directory' switches 
    # in the command line 'gnome-terminal' will pick up 
    # the last one.
    #
    # Also we use full path to executable here in order
    # to prevent recursive calling of 'gnome-terminal' from 
    # '~/bin'.
    /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --working-directory=/ "$@" 
else
    # 'gnome-terminal' was from another directory. 
    # We don't change anything.
    /usr/bin/gnome-terminal "$@"
fi
```

If you run **gnome-terminal** from start menu you will see that current folder in new terminal is `/` (you can use any folder, for example, `~/myfolder` because our custom wrapper is a Bash-script, so shell's expansion with work fine).

If you appeal to **Open in Terminal** in a file manager you will get current directory in the new terminal.

If you run **gnome-terminal** with explicit `--working-directory` parameter (perhaps, from existing terminal instance) new terminal instance will be opened in the directory you specified.

Answer (score 1):

To open in my desired directory as root user I ran:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/my-project/ -x bash -c "sudo su"
```